# Options for sending an image email footer

Tags: email, images

We have our email footers as follows -

Regards

John Doe

Acme Co.

-acme co img logo-

What i was wandering is whats the best way to get the logo into the footer, most email clients support html, so with those you can include images, but will all the images open as default ?

The image isnt particularly, a large 5kb png file, so we dont mind sending it.. but we wandered wether that way the best way.. we could also write `<img src="image route on our server"/>` but im not sure if that would open either or wether users would be asked if they wanted to download the external images.

Comment: The image can be embedded inline, but why don't you first mention which client you're using to compose and send mails?

Comment: @karan, im not sure what the client is, as these are outbound emails that we use in correspondence

Comment: No, I was asking about the client you're using to compose the messages. With Outlook or any decent mail client, you can easily include images in your signature and these will be embedded inline in your HTML mails. Any user with a client capable of displaying HTML mails and whose mail server/security apps haven't blocked the images will be able to see them just fine.

Comment: ahh ok, a mixture of mac mail and thunderbird